# Box needed for outdoor porch light?

Tags: light-fixture, outdoor, junction-box

I am replacing an old outdoor covered porch light fixture with a new LED fixture. The back of the new fixture plate is only about 1 inch max and needs to be flush with the existing wooden support block  6x9x 2" .  The old light had a thicker back plate to accomodate a thin junction box. The new one does not. The wires come through a small 2 inch hole through the 2 inch thick wood support block which is mounted securely  into the house's wood siding.  I can secure the circular metal strap to the wooden block for mounting the light. Must I install a junction box? It would be a lot of trouble to get one recessed into the block.

Comment: I think we're going to need a picture. Since you're new here, you won't be able to add one yourself. Please provide a link to a photo in the comments and someone will edit it in to your post.

Comment: All connections need to be made in an accessable box except for listed splices that are allowed to be covered

Comment: Would the new light fixture mount to a round metal "pancake" box? A pancake box is 1/2" deep and can be flush mounted to a block.